# Hibernate ImprovedNamingStrategy can't get fully qualified class name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss

In the documentation of Jboss for Hibernate, it is stated that

```
ImprovedNamingStrategy.classToTableName(String className)
```

method's **className** argument should return **fully qualified class name**.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html#classToTableName(java.lang.String)

> classToTableName
>
> public String classToTableName(String className)
>
> Return the unqualified class name, mixed case converted to underscores
>
> Specified by:
>
> classToTableName in interface NamingStrategy
>
> Parameters: className
>   - the fully-qualified class name
>
> Returns: a table name

But when I debug the related line in the class that I've extended from **ImprovedNamingStrategy** class, it returns the unqualified class name rather then the fully-qualified one.

What I'm trying to do here is to get the fully-qualified class name to search if any custom annotations has been placed onto that class to decide what prefix should be used when creating the table.

Such as;

```
@CustomAnnotation("PREF_")
@Entity
public class MyEntity{}
```

And using this info Hibernate should create a query like this;

```
CREATE TABLE PREF_MyEntity;
```

I've searched through documentation but couldn't find anything.

Is there a better way to this ? Or is there any best-practice about it?

**== UPDATE ==**

I've both tried package scaning and annotated classes options in the hibernate configurations to see if there any difference, yet no difference is there.

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
   <list>
      <value>com.test.model</value>
   </list>
</property>
```

And

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
      <value>com.test.model.MyEntity</value>
   </list>
</property>
```